# The video starts from the beginning when we set suburi

Tags: gstreamer, python-gstreamer

```
        self.player.set_state(Gst.State.READY)
        self.player.set_property("suburi", name)
        self.player.set_property("subtitle-font-desc", "Sans, 18")
        self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
```

When a certain button is clicked, the above code sets subtitles for video in playing state.
I used the above code to set the subtitles to a video which was already in PLAYING state, when clicked on certain button. When I click on it, subtitles are displayed; but the videos does not resume from current location; it starts over. I also tried the following,

```
        _, duration = self.player.query_duration(Gst.Format.TIME)
        print(duration)
        self.player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        self.player.set_property("uri", self.filename)
        self.player.set_property("suburi", name)
        self.player.set_property("subtitle-font-desc", "Sans, 18")
        self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        self.player.seek_simple(Gst.Format.TIME, Gst.SeekFlags.FLUSH, duration)
```

Even this does not seek. Is there any alternative way to set the suburi without restarting the video?

Comment: Why do you change the state in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

As Florian in their comment pointed out, there is no need to change the state.
Simply set the property `suburi`, although you may also want to look at setting the `flags` property as well.
As in:

```
self.player.set_property('flags', self.GST_VIDEO|self.GST_AUDIO|self.GST_TEXT|self.GST_SOFT_VOLUME|self.GST_DEINTERLACE)
```

when the subtitles are **On**
and:

```
self.player.set_property('flags', self.GST_VIDEO|self.GST_AUDIO|self.GST_SOFT_VOLUME|self.GST_DEINTERLACE)
```

when the subtitles are **Off**

Where the GST properties are declared as:

```
self.GST_VIDEO         = (1 << 0)
self.GST_AUDIO         = (1 << 1)
self.GST_TEXT          = (1 << 2)
self.GST_VIS           = (1 << 3)
self.GST_SOFT_VOLUME   = (1 << 4)
self.GST_NATIVE_AUDIO  = (1 << 5)
self.GST_NATIVE_VIDEO  = (1 << 6)
self.GST_DOWNLOAD      = (1 << 7)
self.GST_BUFFERING     = (1 << 8)
self.GST_DEINTERLACE   = (1 << 9)
self.GST_SOFT_COLORBALANCE = (1 << 10)
```

See: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-playbin.html#GstPlayBin--flags